# SQL Server Problem with carriage splitting a string

Tags: sql-server, string, split

```
DECLARE @Description2 VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Description2 = '1. Each week there will be a philosophical question to address. For example, you will address questions such as do we have freewill or are we determined?, what does quantum physics tell us about the nature of reality?, and what are the philosophical implications of Darwinian evolution? Utilizing the readings for the week prepare a written essay response. There will be a minimum of ten mini-essays for the term and each must be a minimum of 200 words.
2. Develop an argument on the topic of ontology, focusing specifically on the question "Are we just the brain?" Argue either the materialist position (we are just the brain) or the non-materialist position (we are not just the brain), drawing from the primary writings of the philosophers. Be sure to explain both positions in your essay and then make the case for the position you are supporting. This argumentative essay needs to be at least 750 words in length. We will then conduct an in class debate and you will need to argue your point in a debate setting.
3. Develop an argument in the area of ethics, arguing for or against animal rights. Make sure to utilize primary writings in the construction of your argument. This argumentative essay needs to be at least 750 words in length. Students will present their position to the class in a ten minute oral presentation.
4. Having read the writings of Epictetus and Sartre compare and contrast Stoicism and Existentialism. Write a 750 word essay highlighting the key differences and similarities.
5. Analyze the primary readings of Nietzsche in journal form. Choose 10 separate passages to analyze and include the following: a) a summary of the passage; b) an interpretation or analysis of the argument; c) a comparison and/or contrast to the ideas of another philosopher or philosophy; d) personal insight into the writing by applying the ideas to you or to the world at large (its meaning on a deeper, more personal level). This journal will be at least 1000 words in length. '

set @Description2 = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@Description2,'<p>',''),'</p>',''),'<br />',''),'&nbsp;',''),'<br />.<br />',''),'<div>',''),'</div>','')
set @Description2 = concat('???',REPLACE(@Description2,CHAR(13)+char(10),'???'))

select ltrim(s.Item)
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@Description2, '???') s
where ltrim(s.Item) <> ''
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Could you elaborate on what is the issue you have, the actual output you get(a small version will do) and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

So what do you actually want to happen? And what are you seeing that is different from what you want?

In SSMS, if you go to tools > options > query results > SQL Server > results to grid, there is a checkbox labelled "retain CR/LF on copy or save" which determines how varchar data will be treated when you click on the output grid results and copy the data.

If you check the checkbox, the carriage return/linefeed will be retained. Ie, if you do:

```
select 'a
b'
```

Run that query, copy the result from the grid, and paste it into, say, notepad, you will get 2 lines of text in notepad.

On the other hand, if you don't check the checkbox, you will only get a single line in notepad.

Be aware that if you change the setting of this checkbox, I believe you will need to open a new query window to see the new behaviour.

Note that this only controls the behaviour of SSMS. It has nothing to do with how your data is "really" stored, for example, if you insert it into a table. If you have an application reading data from a table, the way it formats the output is up to the application.